# Calculating Tuition Cost Increase Over 5 Years

Tags: python, python-3.7

Still very new to Python programming and learning the basics, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#Define Variables
# x= starting tuition
# y= tuition increae per year
# z = new tuition

#List known Variables
cost = int(25000)
increase = float(.025)

#Calculate the tuiton increase
tuition = cost * increase

 #Calculate the cost increase over 5 years
 #Initialize accumulator for test scores.
total = int(25000)
for x in range(5):
    print('$', format(total+tuition, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Output should be similar to:
Year 1: $25,000
Year 2: $25,625
Year 3: $26,276.63
Year 4: $26,933.54
Year 5: $27,606.88

I am having trouble writing the script so that there is a 2% increase added onto $25,000, then 2% onto $25,625, then 2% increase to equal $26,276.63 etc. etc. for 5 years.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You assume that `tuition` is a function of `cost` while it is of `total`. You should recalculate `tuition` and also modify `total` inside the loop.

Comment: `cost * increase` would actually *decrease* the tuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good choice on python! A few basics...

You don't need to tell python what type your variables are, you just initialise them and python interprets at run time;

```
cost = 25000
increase = 0.025
```

Aside from that your logic/maths seems a little off - as mentioned in the comments you should be recalculating the tuition inside the loop, as the % increase depends on the previous year.

```
cost = 25000
increase = 1.025

print(cost)

for i in range(5)
  cost = cost * increase
  print(f'${str(cost)}')
```

Multiplying by `1.025` is the same as saying 'add 2.5% to the current value'. I'm using a formatted string to print (the `f` before the string says that) - you can put variables or expressions inside the `{}`, as long as they output strings (hence the `str(cost)` which converts the cost to a string to print).

Comment: Thank you For the answer, this was very helpful. Couple questions, how would I modify the print to show each Year's Price? For example, list year 1, year 2, year 3 with the amount. Also, the math her seems to not to match the values I was given by my instructor, they were: Year 1: $25,000
Year 2: $25,625
Year 3: $26,276.63
Year 4: $26,933.54
Year 5: $27,606.88  

Any idea where those values may have came from? Your answer does seem to calculate the 2.5% cost increase from the most recent year correct?

Answer (score 0):

replace the increased value which is %

```
            #Define Variables
            # x= starting tuition
            # y= tuition increae per year
            # z = new tuition

            #List known Variables
            cost = int(25000)
            increase = float(0.02)

            #Calculate the tuiton increase
            tuition = cost * increase
            #Calculate the cost increase over 5 years
            #Initialize accumulator for test scores.
             total = int(25000)

             count = 1


       """use this to print in new line"""
            for x in range(5):

            print('year {}: ${} ' .format(count, total + count * tuition, ',.2f'), sep='')

           count = count + 1

"""use this to print in same line"""
         for x in range(5):

         print('year {}: ${}, ' .format(count, total + count * tuition, ',.2f'), end='')

         count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing same value (increase in ) over and over. Try this:

```
cost = int(25000)
increase = float(1.025)

#Calculate the tuiton increase


 #Calculate the cost increase over 5 years
 #Initialize accumulator for test scores.
total = cost
print('Year 1: ${0:,.2f}'.format(total), end = ' ')
for x in range(2,6):
    total = total*increase
    print('Year {0}: ${1:,.2f}'.format(x,total), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is basically **compound interest** and the formula for that would be `cost * (1+increase)^n` where `n` would be the number of years so far

- So Year 0 `25000 * (1+0.025)^0 = 25000`
- So Year 1 `25000 * (1+0.025)^1 = 25625`
- So Year 2 `25000 * (1+0.025)^2 = 26265.62`
- So Year 3 `25000 * (1+0.025)^3 = 26922.27`
- So Year 4 `25000 * (1+0.025)^4 = 27595.32`

```
cost = int(25000)
increase = float(.025)

for x in range(5):
    tuition = cost*((1.000+increase)**x)
    print(str(x) + ': $', format(tuition, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How would I modify the code to calculate the increase off of the previous year? For example year 1 calculates from year 0, year 2 calculates from year 1 total, year 3 calculates from year 2 total etc.

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand correctly, but if you're saying that instead of Year 0, Year 1 should return $25000 and of instead of Year 1, Year 2 should return $25625... and so on, then the formula `cost * (1+increase)^(n-1)` should work

Comment: The totals should return as: 
Year 1: $25,000
Year 2: $25,625
Year 3: $26,276.63
Year 4: $26,933.54
Year 5: $27,606.88

Each of the answers given here seems to be slightly off that total, not sure why.

Comment: Maybe the `.2f ` in the print statement??